# how to set rules form validation in my custom library in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, set, rules

//  iam trying to load array with input and checking the input then save the data

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Slider{

      public $ci;
       public $ci2;
        protected $CI;
     function __construct() {
                 // reference to the CodeIgniter super object 
         $this->CI =& get_instance();
             $this->ci =&get_instance();
           $this->ci->load->model('Slider_Model');
                   $this->CI->load->library('form_validation');
    }
```

//load array with input and checking the input then save the data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvFPo.png)

```
       function AddSlide($Data){
$this->CI->load->library('form_validation');
$this->CI->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p style="color: red">', '</p>');
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules($Data['Title'],$Data['Title'],'min_length[5]|max_length[20]'); 
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules($Data['Description'],$Data['Description'],'min_length[10]|max_length[100]'); 
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules($Data['Status'],$Data['Status'],'in_list[1,2]');

if ($this->CI->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
   echo FALSE;
}
else
{
   $this->ci->Slider_Model->AddNewSlid($Data);
}

}











}
```

Comment: ci does not equal CI. Make sure $this->ci is $this->CI

Answer (score 0):

please check that your form_validation library is loaded or not

You should need to change this condition

```
if ($this->CI->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
```

to this `if ($this->CI->form_validation->run() == FALSE)`

```
function AddSlide($Data)
{ 
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p style="color: red">', '</p>');
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules($Data['Title'],'sasass','min_length[5]|max_length[20]'); 
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules($Data['decription'],$Data['decription'],'min_length[10]|max_length[100]'); 
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules($Data['status'],$Data['status'],'in_list[1,2]');

if ($this->CI->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
   echo FALSE;
}
else
{
   $this->ci->Slider_Model->AddNewSlid($Data);
}

}
```

Comment: its saving data without checking